# Why System.getProperty does not works as expected

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have Java EE application and in one of its servlets I am using

```
System.getProperty("user.dir")
```

but this returns me my eclipse directory not the project directory !

for testing this I created a test project.. a stand alone Java application project in eclipse and used the same code and it returns the path of the project directory ! (this is what I want)

Question : why the behavior is diff  ? how in my servlet can I get path of the project directory ?

Comment: If you read up about System properties, `user.dir` points to the user's (your) working directory.

Comment: I could be wrong, but the "project directory" is probably not available when a servlet is deployed.  Why would a servlet know about the location of some random Eclipse project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For accessing the path of the project directory from a servlet, try this:

```
request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/")
```

Other than that, `System.getProperty("user.dir")` *is* in fact working as expected, returning the user working directory (which is not necessarily the same as the project's directory). Please read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) first.

Comment: Why read the documentation when you can just go straight to SO and spout off?!?  ;)

Comment: It isn't that jahroy, its just that you need something sometime urgently .. something like when you are fixing a prod issue.. that must go in an hour. But quite true.. that documentation should have been referred first. I will make a note

Answer (score 2):

If you actually read the documentation it says this:

> user.dir  The current working directory when the properties were
>   initialized

Sounds like it's working as expected to me...

From here: http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm

Comment: +1 for reference, but best to link to [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Comment: I would've linked to that, but I found it a little bit too concise ;)